# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in Laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel

Why am i getting an error about Closure serialization here? Neither `$permissionsCacheKey` nor `$permissions` is a Closure, no?

```
public function permissions()
{
    $permissionsCacheKey = 'user_'.$this->id.'_permissions';

    $cache = Cache::get($permissionsCacheKey, function() use ($permissionsCacheKey) {
        $permissions = [];

        foreach ($this->userGroups as $usergroup_id => $usergroup) {
            $permissions = array_merge($permissions, $usergroup->permissions->all());
        }

        Cache::put($permissionsCacheKey, $permissions, 600); <-- Error is on this line accordig to PHP.

        return $permissions;
    });

    return $cache;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried initialising a variable with the `$this->userGroups` before using it in the closure like: `$userGroups = $this->userGroups` and use `$userGroups` in the closure. 
The closure errors are sometimes misleading

Comment: No, ill try that, thanks.

Comment: Still persistent?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, i tried passing `$userGroups` into the closure as `use ($usergroups)` but the error is still there. I also tried moving `Cache::put` outside of the closure, didn't help either.